# Select consecutive number of rows starting from some number

Tags: postgresql, select

What I need is to select 100 consecutive rows from a table, starting at some defined point without ordering data.

As far as I can observe, inserted data to a table is stored in no order but is retrieved by identical `SELECT` statements in the same order.

I could get use of 100 random rows, but random rows are not useful because I always need to retrieve the same data from the database in order to compare results of the algorithm I'm developing.

I don't want to order data by any field because otherwise I'd be biasing the selected data.

The sql statement should be something like:

```
SELECT field1, field2 FROM table1 WHERE row_number > 70000 LIMIT 100;
```

or probably even better (as I think `LIMIT` doesn't prevent the database from outputting every record above row number 70000):

```
SELECT field1, field2 FROM table1 WHERE row_number > 70000 AND row_number <= 70100;
```

What `SELECT` statement should I use?

Comment: Without ordering, you can never be sure that you get the same 100 rows.  If you want to get them in physical order **and** the rows don't get updated or deleted, you can play with the `ctid` column.  Bye the way, why do you need this?

Comment: @dezso: rows don't ever get updated or deleted. It's enough for this case to get them in physical order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like

```
SELECT field1, field2 
FROM table1 
ORDER BY ctid
OFFSET x
LIMIT 100
;
```

As I commented, without ordering you can never be sure that you get the same 100 rows. This way you will get the same rows in a certain order if they don't get updated or deleted.